# Xamarin IOS app application release build going Failed [Error MT1006: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle returned: 0xe8008015.]

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, certificate

I'm trying release my IOS app in iphone Xs Max but going failed and showing above mentioned error. In Dubug mode it's working.

I have tried multiple time by create the certificates and profile with same identifier but getting the same error. My macOS Sonoma 14.1.1 and Xcode version is 15.0.1.

I'm using the Distribution certificate and accordingly Distribution App Store Profile.
All these looks like fine in xcode Manage Certificates.

I have also checks in Visual Studio 2022 Xamarin apple account, all certificates are valid(using import p12 file) and Provisioning profile as well.

In IOS Bundle Signing i'm using the correct Signing Identity with correct Provisioning profile for app release mode.

Also tried to check by changing the Linking Behavior and info.plist Deployment Target(current using 9.0).
Tried with some link avl with Sackoverflow for same error but no luck.

Still getting the same error please help me how to resolve this error

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       error MT1006: Could not install the application '/Users/indranilcoomar/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/LastMileApp/62ed7d0748061c2612abc694d29d1ed1cbaaca880f587cb68be4c1e0da3240b0/bin/iPhone/Release/LastMileApp.app' on the device 'Kettan???s iPhone': AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle returned: 0xe8008015.          0
[image]
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWi2F.png)
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can try to change the `Linker behavior` to 'Do not link',  and then change the build number in the Info.plist (such as from 1.0 to 1.0.1), and the clean & rebuild to see if it works.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the delayed response. Actually the issue get resolved when i used adhoc release and there after i was able to publish the app.  Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the **Signing Identity** and the **Provisioning Profile**. We need to use `Ad-Hoc` rather than use a `Distribution Certificate` to deploy in release mode. So we can publish the app aftewards.

For more detail, see [Ad-Hoc Distribution for Xamarin.iOS Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ad-hoc-distribution?tabs=windows).